# How to make two curves to compare between the values of two before and after variables of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, curve

I have this dataframe

```
df1 = data.frame(x_before = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,2,1),
                 x_after = c(2,1,2,3,6,7,2,2,2,3))
```

and I want to compare between the values of the two variables x_before and x_after using curves. I want them both on the same graph using ggplot. Thanks.

Comment: It is ambiguous whether you want to plot `x` from `df1` against `y` from `df2` or to plot `x` and `y` against their index?

Comment: to make it easier, let's put them together in df1 dataframe. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will draw your variable against index, by status group (before/after)

```
# Import library
library(ggplot2)

# Data-management
df1 <- data.frame(y_before = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,2,1),
                 y_after = c(2,1,2,3,6,7,2,2,2,3))
df <- data.frame(y=c(df1$y_before, df1$y_after),
                 x=c(1:length(df1$y_before),
                     1:length(df1$y_after)),
                 group=c(
                   rep("before", length(df1$y_before)),
                   rep("after", length(df1$y_after))))

# Plot with y as the variable to plot, x being the index, group being the y variable status
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(y=y, x = x, color = group))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. but when there are equal values between the two variables, we see only one of the lines. not the two of them. for example : add to each of y_before and y_after the following values : 2, 2, 2 and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Can you be clear on what output you look after depending on what input. This is very unclear